# Google Maps API on Apple OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, osx-yosemite

I have developed an Asp.Net 4.0 mapping application using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3. All users accessing the website on windows machines report no problems. Same for users on Macs and iPad/iPhones. However, we have a single user who now has a Mac with OS X Yosemite. This user is reporting the following error:

"The provided Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it. Error Code:
InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError"

This error occurs in Chrome and Safari (haven't had them try and install Firefox)

The user is accessing the same exact URL as others, so I don't believe it has anything to do with the referrers stipulated in the API key configuration.

I'm frankly at a bit of a loss as to what could be going on here. Is it possible the increased discontent between Apple and Google has made Apple's latest OS somehow incompatible with Google Maps API? Or am I just missing something simple. Unfortunately, I'm not all that familiar with Apple internet settings. Is there something I need to look at to make sure the new Yosemite platform can pass the API key to Google maps API?

Comment: Well.. I haven't heard this before, and indeed, I am using my Mac to develop my Google Maps app.. can you provide us a demo url which we can take a look at?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the delayed response.. I'm still figuring StackOverflow out. Anyhow, the app is in an intranet and behind security. I don't think I can make a publicly-visible url available anytime soon. I'm still trying to get to the bottom of it with this one user and don't have a lot to go on since she is the only one using Yosemite. I posted here to see if anyone has heard of this issue, and it doesn't look like many have. I will investigate further. if I am able to confirm the issue occurs on all Yosemite machines, I will add that info here.